# Show right click menu on $(".sim-row-edit").mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show right click menu only when I right click on `$(".sim-row-edit").mousedown`. Below is my jQuery code.

Note that when I right-click I see the `alert('Right mouse button!')` message but I don't see the menu.

```
// Function to test right click
  $(".sim-row-edit").mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    // Avoid the real one
    event.preventDefault();
    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").toggle(100).
    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
        top: event.pageY + "px",
        left: event.pageX + "px"
    });
});

// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});

$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
    // This is the triggered action name
    switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
        // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
        case "first": 
            console.log("first"); 
            break;
        case "second": 
            console.log("second");
            break;
        case "third": 
            console.log("third"); 
            break;
    }
  });
      //return false; 
    } 
    //return true; 
  });
```

**html code of menu:**

```
   <a href="#" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link">Portfolio-</a>

    <!-- right click menu -->
    <ul class='custom-menu'>
      <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
      <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
      <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
    </ul>
```

**css menu code:**

```
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index:1000;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:    2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
box-shadow:         2px 2px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #4679BD;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What is wrong in my jQuery code?

Comment: where is .sim-row-edit in your html?

Comment: share the complete example, please

Comment: this is your example https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/5m2nrauw/7/ Maybe it's me that I did not understand the question

Comment: when I click on 'asd' the alert and the menu appear

Comment: right click menu is also coming if we are not clicking above `asd`, question updated, in your fiddle if i click anywhere else right click menu is coming , it should only come if right clicked on `asd` - @Leo

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate mousedown event on another handler and need to change the display property as follows,

$(".custom-menu").css("display", "block");

complete code as follows,

```js
// Function to test right click
  $(".sim-row-edit").mousedown(function(e){
   console.log('ss');
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
   
      // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
 $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
  // Avoid the real one
  event.preventDefault();
  // Show contextmenu
  $(".custom-menu").toggle(100).
  // In the right position (the mouse)
  css({
   top: event.pageY + "px",
   left: event.pageX + "px"
  });
  
 });

 // If the document is clicked somewhere
 $(document).bind("mousedown", function () {
  //$(".custom-menu").hide(100);
 });

 $(".custom-menu li").click(function(){
  // This is the triggered action name
  switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {
   // A case for each action. Should personalize to your actions
   case "first": 
    console.log("first"); 
    break;
   case "second": 
    console.log("second");
    break;
   case "third": 
    console.log("third"); 
    break;
  }
   });
   $(".custom-menu").css("display", "block");
      //return false; 
    } 
    //return true; 
  });
```

Comment: if i right click and click on first,second or third , i am not getting any message in console log

Answer (score -2):

```
I think you forget jQuery library:- 
I just made some small changes: - refer this link

      http://jsfiddle.net/raLn2uh9/5/

        <a href="#" class="sim-row-edit">test</a>
        <ul class='custom-menu'>
          <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
          <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
          <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: If they'd forgotten to include jQuery then it would never work.  The alert wouldn't show as that's fired from within a jQuery event handler.

Comment: I talked about the version and in the given fiddle the solution is working.

Comment: The jQuery event handler in the question already works.  This answer does not add anything.